# Lambda Expressions and Event Subscriptions

Tags: c#, events, lambda

I've heard that if lambda expressions are used to subscribe to an event, then this creates a weak reference to the event handler code, so it is not required to explicitly unsubscribe from the event when the subscriber dies/is no longer interested. Is this true?
E.g.

```
aPersion.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        if (e.PropertyName == "Name")
                        {
                            this.Name = this.TheController.Name;
                        }
                    };
```

Answer (score 2):

No, in the context of event subscriptions lambda expressions are just delegates for all intents and purposes and hence remain prone to Lapsed Listener issues. So no, it's definitely not a weak reference.

[There are a variety of approaches for using weak references to work around this issue, which are summarised well in this post from Damien Guard](http://damieng.com/blog/2005/01/19/lapsedlistenersmemoryleaksinsubscriberpublisherscenarios)

Comment: Thanks very much Ruben - seems WeakEventManager is my new friend in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is myth. Lambdas create regular delegates (in this usage, at least). The confusion is often simply that if the **publishing** object is going to be finished with *before* or at around the *same* time as the **subscriber**, then there is no need to unsubscribe. The event delegate only keeps the *subscriber* aliver, not the *publisher*.

In the example given, therefore, it depends on whether your publisher: `aPersion` (presumably a person or similar) is going to be used *after* the form/page/whatever has finished.